# Twilio Programmable Video - Web Socket error when joining the room

Tags: javascript, angular, video, websocket, twilio

I am creating a programmable video using Twilio Cloud Platform. Currently working locally. 
I have created two clients(Peer-to-Peer communication) for the testing purpose, see the picture below. 
When the button for joining the room is clicked for the first time ever by either client, I get the following error on the console:

```
 index.js:141 WebSocket connection to 'wss://sdkgw.us1.twilio.com/v1/VideoEvents' 
failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.
websocket error
```

I have gone through this [link](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-video.js/issues/576) but it solves the issue for an older version (1.5.x) and my version is 2.x. [image]

how can I fix this websocket error?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this?

Comment: @GustavoSantamaría now, I don't remember that. I can share the working code with you - that worked in Sept'20

Comment: Yes please, would be great